# ActionScript 3.0 Exponent Calculator

Tags: actionscript-3, random, numbers, calculator, helper

If a user enters a base = 3 and an exponent = 4, your program should be able to use a loop to calculate powers as follows: i know I have to use power=Math.pow(baseIn, exponentIn) but other then that im very lost.. learning this my self since im the only person taking the class 
Example:

31 = 3

32 = 9

33 = 27

34 = 81

![enter image description here][1]

**tip**: power=Math.pow(baseIn, exponentIn);

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUkdx.png

Comment: Not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

To use a loop to calculate you would do this.

```
function powerCalc(base:Number, power:Number):Number
{
  var result:Number = 1;
  for (var i:int = 0; i < power; i++)
  {
    result = result * base;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then you can call:

```
var power = powerCalc(3,4);
```